# mongoDB projection on array in an object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, projection

I have this document structure in the collection:

```
{"_id":"890138075223711744",
"guildID":"854557773990854707",
"name":"test-lab",
"game": {
    "usedWords":["akşam","elma","akım"]
    }
}
```

What is the most efficient way to get its fields except the array (it can be really large), and at the same time, see if an item exists in the array ?

I tried this:

```
    let query = {_id: channelID}
    const options = { sort: { name: 1 }, projection: { name: 1, "game.usedWords": { $elemMatch: { word}}}}
    mongoClient.db(db).collection("channels").findOne(query, options);
```

but I got the error: "$elemMatch can not be used on nested fields"

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly you can use this query:

Using positional operator `$` you can return only the matched word.

```
db.collection.find({
  "game.usedWords": "akşam"
},
{
  "name": 1,
  "game.usedWords.$": 1
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g5NPAAaKDWk)

The output is only `name` and the matched `word` (also `_id` which is returned by default)

```
[
  {
    "_id": "890138075223711744",
    "game": {
      "usedWords": [
        "akşam"
      ]
    },
    "name": "test-lab"
  }
]
```

Comment: It works ok but if the array does not include the item, the query returns null. I want other fields like "name" to be returned regardless.

Comment: Is something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n1UetYmuMDa) what are you looking for?

Comment: [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U6TCuKujkil) solves the problem. Credits to Centrax from mongoDB discord server. @J.F.